# How can I use my YubiKey certificate as SSH private/public keys on macOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, ssh, smart-card

The YubiKey provides authentication with PIV. How can I use my YubiKey smart card certificate to connect securely to other hosts with SSH using the public key method?

Answer (score 6):

For doing this you need the Yubikey `libykcs11` library what allows you to use it as ssh private key and if you want load it into ssh-agent.

#### prerequistites: Homebrew, xcode

- install xcode as prerequisite for Homebrew

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

- activate Homebrew https://brew.sh

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

- extend the profile according to the output from Homebrew installation; the following is valid on ARM based MacOS; on Intel Macs the Homebrew base dir is /usr/local

```sh
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> $HOME/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

- install the Yubikey PIV library https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-piv-tool/issues/118

```sh
brew install yubico-piv-tool
```

- Now place the required lib in /usr/local/lib to make it useable for openssh. It is required to **copy** the lib. For security reason just a symlink won't work for MacOS.(remember to search for the lib in /usr/local on a Intel based Macos)

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
sudo cp /opt/homebrew/lib/libykcs11.dylib /usr/local/lib/libykcs11_NOTALINK.dylib
```

#### using your key with openssh

To use your smart-card private key you need to reference the library above to openssh commands.

- just connect with ssh command:

```sh
ssh -I /usr/local/lib/libykcs11_NOTALINK.dylib user@hostname
```

- extracting the public key from the smart-card to be able to use it in .ssh/authorized_keys files or apps like git

```sh
ssh-keygen -D  /usr/local/lib/libykcs11_NOTALINK.dylib -e
```

- loading the smart-card private key into ssh-agent

```sh
ssh-add -s /usr/local/lib/libykcs11_NOTALINK.dylib
```

- removing the smart-card private key from ssh-agent

```sh
ssh-add -d /usr/local/lib/libykcs11_NOTALINK.dylib
```